# How to compare two Shapes in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement following function: One `Shape` (displayed as a stroke) is displayed and the user is supposed to draw this `Shape` again with his fingers. The current approach is:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack{

        // DRAWING FIELD
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged{ value in
                        self.viewModel.addNewPoint(value)
                    }
                    .onEnded{_ in
                        self.viewModel.compareShapes()
                        self.viewModel.removeAllPoints()
                    }
            )
        
        //DISPLAYING SHAPE FOR USER
        MyShape()
            .stroke(lineWidth: 5)

       //DRAWING LINE FROM USER
       DrawnLine(points: viewModel.drawnLine)
            .stroke(lineWidth: 5)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
}

struct MyShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300))
        }
    }
}

struct DrawnLine: Shape {
    var points: [CGPoint]

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        guard let firstPoint = points.first else { return path }

        path.move(to: firstPoint)
        for pointIndex in 1..<points.count {
            path.addLine(to: points[pointIndex])
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class HanziWriterViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var drawnLine: [CGPoint] = []

    public func addNewPoint(_ value: DragGesture.Value){
        self.drawnLine.append(value.location)
    }

    public func removeAllPoints(){
        self.drawnLine.removeAll()
    }

    public func compareShapes(){
        // here I have to compare both shapes
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to compare two Shapes with each other. It would be helpful to know how many percent of the given line are covered by the finger-drawn line. Since I already store all `CGPoints` of my finger-drawn line, I need to compare these points with the given `Shape`. Is there any way to convert the `Shape` to an array of CGPoints? Or any other recommendations how to solve this problem?

[image]

The drawn line is only one single line.

EDIT: Just to clarify my question and the purpose: I need to compare the black line with the blue line, so it's not enough to check whether the CGPoints of the blue line are in the Shape with `shape.contains(point)`

Comment: Your lines are basically just two arrays of CGFloat values. So you could make a diff on the arrays. To get a smoother diff it helps creating an average first and then compare the averages. If you want to know the difference for the long and the short part of the shape, just filter the "main" directions and break it into subarrays and compare them.

Comment: "Your lines are basically just two arrays of CGFloat values" -> Really? How can I get the array of CGFloat values of my Shape? I know that I have the CGPoints of my finger-drawn-line (blue line), but how can I access the CGFloat values of the Shape (black line)?

Comment: Is the black line always straight?

Comment: Yes, it consists of several straight lines